# Flexslider IE8 - issue with short slideshowSpeed value and multiple sliders

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flexslider

I am using Flexslider on a portfolio site with multiple sliders with a short `slideshowSpeed` value (`650ms`). Each slideshow has play/pause on hover. I have discovered that the first slide transitions to the second slide on page load in IE8, however if I increase this value to `1100ms`, the first slide loads normally.

Is it possible to define a different `slideshowSpeed` for IE8? Or is there another way to prevent the IE8 issue?

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  controlNav: false,
  directionNav: false,
  slideshowSpeed: 1100, // 650ms causes IE8 to skip to 2nd slide on page load
  animationSpeed: 0,
  mousewheel: false,
  start: function(slider){
    slider.pause();
  }
});

$('.flexslider').each(function(){
  $(this).hoverIntent(
    function(){
        $(this).flexslider('play');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).flexslider('pause');
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this issue by using jQuery's `$.support` method to conditionally define a slower speed for IE8.

```
var speed = 650; // faster speed for good browsers

if (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) {
  // slower speed for IE8, otherwise it skips 1st slide on page load
  speed = 1150; 
}

$(thumbs).flexslider({
  slideshowSpeed: speed,
  // all other options as per code in question above
});
```